# how do this animation [flash]

Tags: flash, animation, web

can anyone hint which programs to create such a professional Flash animation?
    flash site : http://intercarsmotorshow.pl

thx

Answer (score 0):

1. Static image background (3dmax, maya, aftereffects, photoshop)
2. Various video files positioned on area where there is animation (3dmax, maya, aftereffects)
3. Overlay popups flash stage2d library items containing pictures and maybe a few videos
4. Icons at base are movieclip buttons which activate a video, alpha tween between 2 background on mouse over